# Sinch app-to-phone calling can't hear dial tone sometimes

Tags: ios, sinch

i'm using Sinch iOS SDK to call from app-to-phone.
i'm testing it by dialing to another mobile i have and when I let it ring some of the calls play the dial ringing tone and some don't.  I can't reproduce a pattern that causes this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Its actually depends on what carrier you are calling, if you log on callProgressing you will notice that the onprogressing wont fire sometimes until much later for the ones that play no ringing (AT&T is one that dont playit).

To give the user some feedback while waiting for progress, you can play a local ringback (you can find that file in our sample apps) until you get callProgress.